# Pause Nivo Slider

Tags: nivo-slider, loaded

I'd like to pause the Nivo slider for 5 seconds before it runs but show the first image. So I'll need to add some code in the property `afterLoad` I believe.

I've tried `setTimout` before running the slider code be it doesn't give the result I'd like.

This is my current code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        animSpeed: 500,
        pauseTime: 4000,
        effect : 'boxRain',
        directionNav : false,
        controlNav: false,
        afterLoad: function(){
            //$('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();       
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know your exact code but you could use .stop() on it and after 5 seconds you start it again.
<strike>$('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop(); //Stop the Slider
$('#slider').data('nivoslider').delay(5000).start(); //Start the Slider</strike>

Correction (because delay didn't work in that case):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
   animSpeed: 500,
   pauseTime: 4000,
   effect : 'boxRain',
   directionNav : false,
   controlNav: false,
  });
  jQuery('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
  setTimeout("jQuery(#slider').data('nivoslider').start()",5000);
});
```

Comment: Firebug is giving me this `$("#slider").data("nivoslider") is undefined`

Comment: you should replace "#slider" by your slider-id (you probably knew that) and try executing it on windowload.

Comment: Already doing that =\ I'll edit the question to show my code.

Comment: Great, I only need it to stop, do something, then restart, so I used: `jQuery('.nivoSlider').data('nivoslider').stop(); do-something...  jQuery('.nivoSlider').data('nivoslider').start();`.