# Nivo Slider Delay only the first image

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

IT WORKS!!!
http://jsfiddle.net/jupago/W6CkP/

Based on this thread: [Pause Nivo Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135625/pause-nivo-slider)

I was able to figure make it stop on the first image.

**Here's my code. I'm stopping the animation twice because I want it to also stop after slideshow ends:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 5000,
    startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav: true,  // Next & Prev navigation
    controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    pauseOnHover: false, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
    prevText: 'previous', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'next', // Next directionNav text
    randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
    slideshowEnd: function(){           
          $('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
    setTimeout("$('#slider').data('nivoslider').start()",10000);
        }, // Triggers when last slide is shown
    });

    $('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
    setTimeout("$('#slider').data('nivoslider').start()",10000);
 });
```

---

Original post here:

I'm using the NIVO slider plugin and while I got it to work smoothly, I need the first image to last longer than the rest (First image has text in it).

I've created a working fiddle here: [jsfiddle.net/jupago/W6CkP](http://jsfiddle.net/jupago/W6CkP)

that should make it a lot easier to understand the issue.
I'm still attaching html code from fiddle before for reference:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="http://goo.gl/I4c65" />
<img src="http://goo.gl/acxBF"/>
<img src="http://goo.gl/GBzYF"/>
<img src="http://goo.gl/BC2EA" />
<img src="http://goo.gl/9Sd69" />
<img src="http://goo.gl/qOaZl"/>
<img src="http://goo.gl/btswq" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS NIVO:

```
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 5000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav: true,  // Next & Prev navigation
    controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    pauseOnHover: false, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
    prevText: 'next', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'previous;', // Next directionNav text
    randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
    beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
    afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
    slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
    lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
    afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, so I cannot guarantee that it will work, but one of the things that you could try is actually setting the `pauseTime` to a function instead of a constant, `5000`. You would determine what image you are on, then, if it is the desired image, you would set the time to something like `8000`, otherwise you would set it to `5000`.

Just to reiterate: I have NOT tested this, nor can I guarantee that it will work. However, if it does, it would provide you with a significant amount of extra flexibility.

Here is the code that you would use if you wanted to try to implement this:

```
...
pauseTime: function() {
    if ($("#slider").data("nivo:vars").currentSlide == 0) {
        return 8000;
    }
    return 5000;
},
...
```

Alternatively, if this doesn't work in the `pauseTime`, then I would try putting nearly the same thing into othe `beforeChange` option, like so:

```
...
beforeChange: function() {
    if ($("#slider").data("nivo:vars").currentSlide == 0) {
        $("#slider").delay(3000);
    }
    return;
},
...
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** You should actually replace the `....currentSlide == 0)` in the samples above with the accessor for the Nivo Slider's `startSlide` option, especially if you ever plan to change the start index of the slider. I do not remember what the accessor is, but I would imaging that it would look something like:

```
....currentSlide == settings.startSlide)
```

where `settings` is the name of the settings variable that Nivo uses.

**UPDATE**

Based on the errors you mentioned in your comments, my next suggestion is that you try the same two solutions again, but this time replace the `setting.startSlide` with `0`. If that does not work (though it should), then we need to go back to the drawing board. If it does work, try replacing the `0` with `this.startSlide`. Let me know how this works out.

Comment: thanks @Zachary Kniebel this seems like the simplest version but I can't seem to get it to work. Trying to upload the files on a temporary folder to see if that helps. I tried using settings.startSlide since I believe thats the variable Nivo is using but in threw a bunch of errors

Comment: You're welcome. You are correct that the name of the variable is `settings`. Can you add the updated code and errors to your post, as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Zachary Kniebel, when I try to set pauseTime as a function it goes crazy into a non-stop spin. And when I insert your second example with the accessor chorme gives me this:  Uncaught ReferenceError: settings is not defined

Comment: I have added an update to my post that gives you some suggestions. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Zachary Kniebel, no luck yet.  Created a fiddle. (http://jsfiddle.net/jupago/W6CkP/) hope this helps. Thank you so much! –

Comment: @Jupago - I'm sorry but I really can't put anymore time into this, right now. I will try to return to it when I can

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
 $(window).load(function() {
   var waited = false;
   $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    //...
    beforeChange: function(){
        if(!waited && ($('#slider').data("nivo:vars").currentSlide == 0)) { //first slide
            //wait a little longer
            $('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
            setTimeout(function(){
                 waited = true;
                 $('#slider').data('nivoslider').start();
            }, 2000); //2 seconds
        } else {
            waited = false;
        }
    },
    //...
    });
});
```

**EDIT :** I don't know if the settimeout is really necessary, maybe only `return false` would do it.

```
 $(window).load(function() {
   var waited = false;
   $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    //...
    beforeChange: function(){
        if(!waited && ($('#slider').data("nivo:vars").currentSlide == 0)) { //first slide
            //wait a little longer
            return false;
        } else {
            waited = false;
        }
    },
    //...
    });
});
```

Comment: Check your two syntax errors on the second line of your setTimeout function (though the second is just a semi-colon, so technically that one is okay)

Comment: This solution is likely to work, but I always consider setTimeout to be a Pis Aller

Comment: thanks @Philippe Boissonneault! I almost got it to work. The weird thing that is going on is that with this code is the SECOND image that gets delayed, not the first. Not sure what to do since the startSlide is already set to 0

Comment: I don't know if it is the solution, but instead of using settimeout, try only `return false` (see edit)

Comment: Thanks @Philippe Boissonneault, but where would I set the delay time on the second option?

Comment: This should, in theory, play the first slide twice. So the delay would be 2*`pauseTime`. You can alternatively set a javascript delay instead of `return false` but this would be the second solution by @ZacharyKniebel.

Comment: fyi just updated/simplified fiddle, didn't realized I didnt save it before

Comment: arghhhh.. sorry im getting used to the fiddle here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/jupago/W6CkP/

Answer (score 0):

I've done this and works fine:

In your HTML page change:

```
$(window).load(function() {  
     $('#slider').nivoSlider({...
```

by

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({...
```